# Is it okay to use mismatching tires?

Tags: tire

I own a Vittoria Rubino Pro Slick 700x23 and a Conti GP4000S 700x25.

What do you guys think about:

1. mounting different tires on a bike?
2. which tire should go where? The Vittoria has around 200 miles on it and Conti has less than a 100.

Comment: See also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9308/should-i-put-my-wider-tire-in-front-or-in-back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Certain manufacturers sell different tires for front and back and I have run different tires on front and back on multiple bikes when one tire is worn or punctured and needed to be replaced, but the other tire still has tread/life.  Mixing brands isn't an issue other than one tire wearing faster than the other one.
2. It shouldn't matter which tire goes where, but judging at the rate that my tires wear, put the newer tire on the back since it will wear faster than the front tire. I usually move the older tire to the front since it will wear slower and if there are punctures caused by the age of the tire, it is easier to replace a front tire than a back..

Comment: From the question I can see the two mentioned tires are two different widths. Would tire width effect the placement at all?

Comment: From a functionality standpoint, not a lot of difference for general use (regarding where to place according to width). There are some aerodynamic considerations, but that also varies depending on rim type/shape, etc.

Comment: @Merri - In general, the wider tire should go on back, both because of the greater weight on the rear, and because a narrower tire steers more easily.  However, one might go the other way if regularly riding on relatively irregular surfaces, since the wider tire is less likely to "squirt" out from under you on a bump.

Comment: Also the ornament on the tire doesn't matter